# (SOLVED) How to make looping easier, then just changing the loop number in Python

Tags: python, loops, instagram, screen-scraping

How to make looping **arguments[0].scrollTop** more simple? let say if i want to make it looping 20x then i just change the looping number..

```
for i in range(1, loops_count + 1):
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(6, 10))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(6, 10))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(6, 10))
    browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
    time.sleep(random.randrange(6, 10))
    

    all_div = followers_ul.find_elements_by_tag_name("li")
    for us in all_div:
        us = us.find_element_by_tag_name("a").get_attribute("href")
        if result == 'usernames':
            us1 = us.replace("https://www.instagram.com/", "")
            us = us1.replace("/", "")
        followers_list.append(us)
    time.sleep(4)
    f3 = open('userlist.txt', 'w')
    for list in followers_list:
        f3.write(list + '\n')
    print(f'Got: {len(followers_list)} usernames of {amount}. Saved to file.')
time.sleep(random.randrange(5, 7))
```

I add nested loop

```
for i in range(1, loops_count + 1):
    for j in range(1,31):
        browser.execute_script(f"arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
```

Comment: maybe just try for i in range(20):

Comment: To be clear: the question is about how to repeat the two lines of code `browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul)` and `time.sleep(random.randrange(6, 10))`, a set number of times, instead of having to copy and paste it for each time? **You already know how to do this, and are already using that technique in the code**. Hint: where the code says `for i in range(1, loops_count + 1):`, what does that mean?

Comment: so that whole code already have looping... but i want to add new looping on specify > .scrollTop.. 

example when i set whole code looping for 50x, i want to make every action,  (.scrollTop) will looping lets say 20x..
so it will have 2 different looping...

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem to use another `for`-loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it's what you're searching, you can do :

```py
for i in range(1, loops_count + 1):
    browser.execute_script(f"arguments[{i}].scrollTop = arguments[{i}].scrollHeight", followers_ul)
```

Adding f"{variable}" to a string is a simple way to have a string with variable.
In this case, it will replace in the string the i the loop count.
If it's not that, could you precise your question ?

Comment: here sir.. so that whole code already have looping... but i want to add new looping on specify > .scrollTop.. 

example when i set whole code looping for 50x, i want to make every i action, that .scrollTop will looping lets say 20x..
so it will have 2 different looping

Comment: great thank sir.... i make nested like this

' for i in range(1, loops_count + 1):
     for j in range(1,31):
      browser.execute_script(f"arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", followers_ul) '